# How to connect a usb device (midi keyboard) from a 10 meter distance?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, usb, keyboard, ethernet

I'm looking for a way to connect a usb device (midi keyboard) 10 meters away from my pc. Usb cables are maxed out at 5 meter. And as it is fully USB powered, it won't be able to function correctly.

The USB I need is something like this:

[image: usb cable]

I've been trying to find if it's possible to connect it through an ethernet cable, but I'm not really sure how that should work or how the needed devices would be called.

Any ideas on how to connect a device from such a distance? Can it be done over ethernet?

Answer (score 2):

Google "long USB cable" or be specific as to your required length.

You can get cables with repeaters in the middle to traverse long distances. Many stores & online retailers carry them.

USB 2 can travel about 5m before it needs a repeater.

There's a good explanation at http://www.yourcablestore.com/USB-Cable-Length-Limitations-And-How-To-Break-Them_ep_42-1.html

> **Active (Repeater) Extension Cables:**
>
> USB active extension cables contain electronics that regenerate the
>   USB signal. Active cables are essentially 1 port USB hubs. You can use
>   a regular USB cable in conjunction with an active cable as long as the
>   regular cable is not more than 5 meters (16 feet and 5 inches) long
>   for 2.0 devices and not more than 3 meters (9 feet and 10 inches) long
>   for 3.0 devices. Note: Typically, active cables are bus-powered
>   cables. To ensure you receive the full 500mA power of a USB port,
>   consider purchasing an active cable that includes a separate power
>   adapter.

Comment: My experience with active USB cables hasn't been impressive.  If you need to connect multiple devices from a distance greater than the standard allows you might consider other alternatives (wireless USB devices, etc) and/or (network devices)

Comment: I have two in use. One for my camera remote, at 15m, the other for a wireless keyboard/mouse setup to carry the wifi dongle 10m nearer to where I need to be. Both have been reliable so far.

Comment: @Ramhound In the past I had similar experences as you, however I had to get a 15' active repeater for my Oculus Rift sensors and have not had any issues with them and they require quite a bit of bandwidth.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I have a tall case, I like it being on the ground, the problem is I like my devices to be on my desk.  This means I have to run longer cords, in my experience when multiple active usb cables are used, Windows runs into a USB resource problem.  I recently learned that a simple solution is to get extender cables that are short enough they are within the standard as a work around to my experiences.